# Azure Function App and multiple Functions within it, performance

Tags: c#, .net, azure

I am new to Azure Function App. I am using a consumption plan.

Does it make a difference how many functions are in a Function App?

What about if there are functions, such as the service bus triggered function, which is no longer called? Should these be deleted?

For example, I have MyFunctionApp

It has an IoT Hub Trigger, HTTP Trigger Function, A, B, C, and D few service bus functions and a few inactive functions.

I am not sure if I have understood this, but I have read if we were to trigger any Function, such as Function A. It would create an instance of the entire Function App in Memory, which would also affect the CPU usage.

Is this Correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am trying to improve performance and want to know if there is a lot of function in the Function App, does that effect performance overall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason to get rid of unused functions is because they're distracting clutter that slow down humans trying to solve problems. For an excessive number of functions to become something your cloud provider cares about you'd need enough that their signatures were the majority of your code. And that only because it makes the binary larger. Still, doubt most would care.

What matters to cloud providers is consuming resources like memory space and CPU time. I see no indication that this significantly impacts either. Worrying about performance without testing performance is a good way to waste your time and money.